# Problem with the L prefix ( LPCWSTR typecast) in winAPI

Tags: c, winapi, win32gui, lpcwstr

I'm new to winAPI and encountered a problem I can't seem to solve... Couldn't find a solution by google yet, either.

My program has several buttons of similar size so I made a macro to hide all the mess. The original macro was:

```
#define _BUTTON(s, x, y, v)    CreateWindowW(L"Button", (L)s, WS_VISIBLE | WS_CHILD, x, y, 75, 25, hWnd, (HMENU)v, 0, 0);
```

However, "`L(s)`" doesn't work with or without the parenthesis, on `s` or `L`. I also tried replacing `L` with `LPCWSTR`, `WCHAR*`, `_T()`, etc... The compiler error is always the same: `"L (or LPCWSTR, etc) is not declared in this scope"` although I thought it should be...

For now I resolved the issue by going with the non-Unicode:

```
#define _BUTTON(s, x, y, v)    CreateWindow("Button", s, WS_VISIBLE | WS_CHILD, x, y, 75, 25, hWnd, (HMENU)v, 0, 0);
```

But I'd like all the windows to support the same chars... Where is the problem?

Comment: Unrelated to your problem, but in C all symbols beginning with an underscore followed by either another underscore or an upper-case letter (as in `_BUTTONS`) are *reserved* and you should not define such symbols yourself.

Comment: Also note that `CreateWindow` is really a *macro* that will be expanded to either `CreateWindowA` or `CreateWindowW` depending on the existence of the `UNICODE` macro.

Comment: `CreateWindowW(WC_BUTTON, L##s, ` for example

Comment: Lastly for a way to "solve" your problem: Why not simply use `CreateWindowW` like in the first example, but let the users of the macro pass the correct type of strings? I.e. document the macro as needing a wide-character string for the first argument. If the users don't read the documentation or just don't care about it, then they will get build errors.

Comment: or even use `#define echo(x) x` and `echo(L)##echo(s)`

Comment: @RbMm thanks for the quick reply and solution! seems to work now!

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude well I didn't know that! We didn't cover it when I learned C, and winAPI I'm learning on my own... Thanks for the advice - gonna change it!

Comment: See e.g. [this reserved identifier reference](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/language/identifier#Reserved_identifiers) for details.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude Thanks! (can't like yet)

Comment: Why is `_BUTTON` even a macro to begin with? What's wrong with a function? It's the most fundamental abstraction we have in C. Just use it.

Comment: @IInspectable I find that it's easier to edit 15 statics, buttons, edits and listboxes as a macro (visually speaking). Otherwise searching for the right argument make me sad...

Comment: I fail to see, how editing a function is any more troublesome than editing a macro. If nothing else you'll get IntelliSense support in functions.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One way is what RbMm metioned, like:

```
#define Create_Button(s, x, y, v)     CreateWindowW(L"Button", L##s, WS_VISIBLE | WS_CHILD, x, y, 75, 25, hWnd, (HMENU)v, 0, 0);
```

Another way is to use a common approach:

```
#define Create_ButtonA(s, x, y, v)    CreateWindowA("Button", s, WS_VISIBLE | WS_CHILD, x, y, 75, 25, hWnd, (HMENU)v, 0, 0);
#define Create_ButtonW(s, x, y, v)    CreateWindowW(L"Button", s, WS_VISIBLE | WS_CHILD, x, y, 75, 25, hWnd, (HMENU)v, 0, 0);
#ifdef _UNICODE
#define Create_Button(s, x, y, v)     Create_ButtonW(s, x, y, v)
#else
#define Create_Button(s, x, y, v)     Create_ButtonA(s, x, y, v)
#endif
```

Usage:

```
Create_Button(TEXT("name"),10,10,2);
Create_ButtonA("name",10,10,2);
Create_ButtonW(L"name",10,10,2);
```